# iDangerous Swiper plugin fade div on active slide and fade out on swipe

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I am trying to setup swiper so that it fades in a div on each slide.

The slides would look like this

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x200?text=Promotion&bg_color=e6e6e6&text_color=ffffff" class="animated fadeInUp"/>
            <div class="card-actions">
            Form field<br>
            Button
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want it to slide as normal but fade in the div with the class card-actions for each slide when it is the active slide and then when you start to slide to next slide i want it to fade out. Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: here is a fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/od7m1q99/. Is this correct? Seems to work but is buggy when swiping a lot and going back and forth from slides. Sometimes does not show active slide div.

Comment: also here is a test with loop set to true and it does not work at all https://jsfiddle.net/od7m1q99/1/

What would cause the loop not to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use callbacks for that, for example (jQuery should be included):

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  onSlideChangeEnd: function (swiper) {
    $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
        if ($(this).index() === swiper.activeIndex) {
            // Fadein in active slide
            $(this).find('.card-actions').fadeIn(300);
        }
        else {
            // Fadeout in inactive slides
            $(this).find('.card-actions').fadeOut(300);   
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: WOW! this is almost perfect. When it first loads it is showing all of the divs that should fade in. I am trying to get it show the first one on the first slide and not the others until you swipe. Then they fade out when not on the active slide.

Comment: I setup a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/od7m1q99/ and tried adding onInit, onSliderMove before the onSlideChangeEnd and it seems to be working ok bur sometimes it is buggy if you swipe back and forth a lot and does not display the div for the active slide. Is this correct the way i have this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you modify the Swiper **Effect** Parameter to fade as `effect:fade`. For more options visit their [Api Documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WVnc8Jr1_Dc).

Comment: The `fade` effect only works for backgrounds i think .