# idangerous swiper 2 - fade effect manually

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I can't update my swiper to version 3.x that has effects options because of customizations in css and html that are in the production servers of my customers (the project is a CMS and They can change properties like bullets, arrows, size, loop, color etc).

Is there a way to implement this effect easily using callbacks? Any other suggestion is aprreciate.

`code:` https://jsfiddle.net/rya3Lfdy/1/

[This post can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591076/idangerous-swiper-plugin-fade-div-on-active-slide-and-fade-out-on-swipe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Vladimir Kharlampidi [nolimits4web]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1923913/vladimir-kharlampidi)** helped me in github showing a plugin for Swipe 2 that solved my problem.

[Swiper Smooth Progress](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper-Smooth-Progress)